# Joining lines in order of different blocks in the same text file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file split in blocks like the following:

```
AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTGGGG
AGGTAGTTATTATTTTTTTGGTTTTTAGTATTTAATTGAGTGTTT
ATGTAGGTGTTTATGTATTAGTTTTTTTTAGGTTTAGGGTGTTGT
ATTTAGGTTTTGTGTTTTGTGTATTATTGAATTTAATTAAAGTTA

AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTT
AGTTTTTTTTTATTTGTCGGGATATTTTAGTTGATTTTAGATTGC
TATATTTTTAGTTTCGATTCGTCGTAAGTTTTATTTTTTTTTAAT
GGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTTT
```

I've truncated/wrapped the lines for clarity's sake, but imagine very long lines. The point of my question is that I want a final file that looks like this:

```
AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTGGGGAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTT
AGGTAGTTATTATTTTTTTGGTTTTTAGTATTTAATTGAGTGTTTAGTTTTTTTTTATTTGTCGGGATATTTTAGTTGATTTTAGATTGC
ATGTAGGTGTTTATGTATTAGTTTTTTTTAGGTTTAGGGTGTTGTTATATTTTTAGTTTCGATTCGTCGTAAGTTTTATTTTTTTTTAAT
ATTTAGGTTTTGTGTTTTGTGTATTATTGAATTTAATTAAAGTTAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTTT
```

Where this new block has:

1. the same number of lines as the initial blocks,
2. each of the lines of the resulting block is a concatenation of the lines with the same line-number in the initial blocks.
3. this concatenation should be in-order (i.e. "1st line of 1st block" + "1st line of 2nd block", etc

Is it possible to achieve this final block using `sed` and/or `awk`, could you show me how it could be done?

Comment: Do you just want to know **if** it can be done with sed/awk, or **how** it is done?

Comment: Sorry, I changed IF for HOW.. :(

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` with `paste`:

```
$ paste <(head -4 file) <(tail -4 file) | tr -d '\t'
AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTGGGGAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTT
AGGTAGTTATTATTTTTTTGGTTTTTAGTATTTAATTGAGTGTTTAGTTTTTTTTTATTTGTCGGGATATTTTAGTTGATTTTAGATTGC
ATGTAGGTGTTTATGTATTAGTTTTTTTTAGGTTTAGGGTGTTGTTATATTTTTAGTTTCGATTCGTCGTAAGTTTTATTTTTTTTTAAT
ATTTAGGTTTTGTGTTTTGTGTATTATTGAATTTAATTAAAGTTAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTTT
```

Comment: what if the files have more than 4 lines? (he's not saying they could, but using `wc -l` or even `cat` could be added for completeness' sake)

Comment: @Oerd I think you mean what if each block has more than 4 lines.. and if this is the case it's pretty clear to increase the number of lines read by `head` and `tail` to the number of lines in the blocks.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant. probably over-thinking this one for his level of command-line-foo

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 awk -vOFS="" '$0{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR/2;i++)print a[i],a[i+5]}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat tmp.txt
AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTGGGG
AGGTAGTTATTATTTTTTTGGTTTTTAGTATTTAATTGAGTGTTT
ATGTAGGTGTTTATGTATTAGTTTTTTTTAGGTTTAGGGTGTTGT
ATTTAGGTTTTGTGTTTTGTGTATTATTGAATTTAATTAAAGTTA

AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTT
AGTTTTTTTTTATTTGTCGGGATATTTTAGTTGATTTTAGATTGC
TATATTTTTAGTTTCGATTCGTCGTAAGTTTTATTTTTTTTTAAT
GGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTTT

kent$  awk -vOFS="" '$0{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR/2;i++)print a[i],a[i+5]}' tmp.txt
AGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTGGGGAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTT
AGGTAGTTATTATTTTTTTGGTTTTTAGTATTTAATTGAGTGTTTAGTTTTTTTTTATTTGTCGGGATATTTTAGTTGATTTTAGATTGC
ATGTAGGTGTTTATGTATTAGTTTTTTTTAGGTTTAGGGTGTTGTTATATTTTTAGTTTCGATTCGTCGTAAGTTTTATTTTTTTTTAAT
ATTTAGGTTTTGTGTTTTGTGTATTATTGAATTTAATTAAAGTTAGGATAGGTTTTGGTGTTTGAGGTTAATTTTGTTTTATTTTTTTTT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {str[i] = str[i] $i} END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print str[i]}' file
```